# Tire/Elasticsearch Filtering on Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

so when clients are logged into the app they should only be able to search within their company so we are trying to filter on client name. The log output appears to be correct though but no search results are being returned.

```
#report.rb
def self.search_for_client(params, client)
 tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 20) do
  query  { string params[:q] } if params[:q].present?
  filter :term, :client => client
 end
end

#reports_controller.rb
def full_search
 @query = params[:q]
 if current_user.client.nil?
  @results = Report.search params
 else
  @results = Report.search_for_client params, current_user.client.title
 end
end

#log output
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/reports/report/_search?load=true&size=20&pretty' -d '{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"thio"}},"filter":{"term":{"client":"ApplusRTD Norway"}},"size":20}'
```

Comment: Is your client term "ApplusRTD Norway" analyzed in your index? Term filters don't analyze the term provided http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-filter.html

Comment: Also you may want to use http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html#query-dsl-filtered-query instead of a queryStringquery and a filter. Zachary Tong gives a great explanation in his slide show here: https://speakerdeck.com/polyfractal/elasticsearch-query-optimization

Comment: thanks for that, i'll check those resources.

Comment: Congrats, on finding the answer, hope those helped.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the main issue was that I was not restarting the elasticsearch server after indexing. I've tweaked the search_for_client method also.

```
#report.rb
def self.search_for_client(params, client)
tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 20) do
  query do
    boolean do
      must { string params[:q], default_operator: "AND" } if params[:q].present?
      must { string 'status:active' }
    end
  end
  filter :term, :client => [client]
end
```

end

```
#output
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/reports/report/_search?size=20&pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "UT-12-541"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "client": [
        "Fabricom GDF Suez"
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 20
}'
```